# QProgressBar rendering is not good

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I have added a qprogressbar to a form in qt designer, and set minimum and maximum value to 0 to show the in-progress state. but when I run the application progress bar is displayed with the shadow mark as shown in this pic...

[image]

Same thing happens when I add QProgressDialog from the code.. could some one suggest me how to avoid this problem ?

I am using qt 4.8.4 sdk with qt creator 2.8.0 in Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: as I told already this issue exists even when a Progress bar is added to a Form in Qt designer and run, one thing is to add is some times the progress bar looks normal but most of the times the moving bar comes with shadow

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're allowing the progressbar to resize vertically. It can't. You must set its vertical size policy to fixed.

Comment: No, vertical size policy is "Fixed". only Horizontal Policy I set to "Expanding", But no clue why its happening like this ??

Comment: Hook up a timer to a slot somewhere, and poll the vertical size of the progressbar and output a message every time it changes from the old value. It looks like the progress bar is resizing.